# Scanning barcode on headless Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian

I am working on a project in which I would like to read barcode data and send them to raspberry Pi.

I am wondering if it is possible to perform that while raspberry Pi is running headless. Meaning, could I program the Raspberry Pi such that once the power is plugged in, it reads the barcode data and send it to a microcontroller?

Comment: Your question is too vague. You need to provide more specific details in order to get a proper answer. The Pi running headless is able to recieve data and process it. How you achieve this depends on the specific process you have in mind.

Answer (score 5):

most contemporary barcode readers pretend to be HID (human interface device, read: keyboard, mouse) and send plain clear text of the barcode read to wherever you connect it to.

you don't need any TV monitor or display, just connect your reader to (preferably) USB port, login from the network and run simple scripts reading data and doing whatever you'd like them to do.

ps. what keeps me still awake is the question, why do you need to send the barcode to the microcontroller, but that's totally irrelevant here =)

Comment: I need somehow to integrate more than one device together, like connect more than one barcode scanner alone with mp3.. something like that..

Comment: The reason am asking about running the raspberry pi headless is that when we boot the pi we see black screen that shows the booting process... so I was wondering if it would be possible to just use the pi to process the barcode data immediately, without going into the booting process... I would like to add that am a newbie to raspberry pi, that is why am asking this :)

Comment: @Guest you need to boot linux first and run your scripts second, there's no way around it. fortunately, boot process does not take more than a few seconds.